# Print docplex solve() results in a dataframe

Tags: python, docplex

I have created a optimization model using docplex package.

This is how I have defined the decission variable.

```
x = {(i.supply,i.demand,i.product): tm.integer_var(name='x_{0}_{1}_{2}'.format(i.supply,i.demand,i.product),ub=10000000) for i in cost_list}
```

Using `tms = tm.solve()` I was managed to get the results.

`type` of the tms is `<class 'docplex.mp.solution.SolveSolution'>`.
my output as follows.

```
solution for: transportation
objective: 60
x_1_3_a = 1
x_1_3_b = 3
```

I need to put the `x_1_3_a = 1 & x_1_3_b = 3` in a dataframe(`x,1,3,a,1` results are in different columns).Can someone advise how I can do this.

```
---After the edit---
```

Expected output pandas dataframe as follows.

```
Var,supply,demand,product,qty
x,1,3,a,1
x,1,3,b,3
```

Comment: Not sure I follow the last statement. Would would you like the dataframe to look like, exactly? Could you please provide the expected output?

Comment: @Roy2012 updated the question as per your advise

Comment: Sorry, can't help. You need to purchase ILOG to use this package.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the variable names on '_' and directly create the data for the dataframe, like in this short code snippet:

```
with Model() as m:
    x = m.binary_var_list([1, 2, 3], name='x')
    m.minimize(m.sum(x))
    sol = m.solve(log_output = True)
    print(dir(sol))
    print(sol)
    data = [v.name.split('_') + [sol.get_value(v)] for v in m.iter_variables()]
    frame = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [ 'var', 'index', 'value'])
    print(frame)
```

This prints

```
  var index  value
0   x     1      0
1   x     2      0
2   x     3      0
```

and should work for variables with more than one dimension as well.